# How to convert a namespace URI to a prefix with lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

`lxml` stores all qualified names with the full namespace URI, e.g.

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring('''
<a:doc xmlns:a="http://somesite.org/markup" xmlns:b="http://anothersite.org/markup" a:attr="foo">
  <b:e b:attr="bar"/>
</a:doc>''')

for el in root.iter():
    print("Element", el.tag)
    for a in el.attrib:
        print("  Attribute", a)
```

Will print

```
Element {http://somesite.org/markup}doc
  Attribute {http://somesite.org/markup}attr
Element {http://anothersite.org/markup}e
  Attribute {http://anothersite.org/markup}attr
```

But what if I need more human-readable output with namespace prefixes instead of URIs? Like

```
Element a:doc
  Attribute a:attr
Element b:e
  Attribute b:attr
```

Certainly, I can write the conversion function myself, e.g.

```
def uri2prefix(name, nsmap):
    qname = etree.QName(name)
    for pref, uri in nsmap.items():
        if qname.namespace == uri:
            return pref + ':' + qname.localname
    return name

for el in root.iter():
    print("Element", uri2prefix(el.tag, el.nsmap))
    for a in el.attrib:
        print("  Attribute", uri2prefix(a, el.nsmap))
```

But there must be the same functionality somewhere in `lxml`, because `lxml.etree.tostring()` uses it. Unfortunately I couldn't find it in the documentation. May be someone knows a magic function doing the job?

Comment: Elements have a `prefix` property: https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#prefix. There is no such property for attributes though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any better solution than using your *uri2prefix* function.

The only improvement can be for element: a `_Element` instance has a *prefix* attribute. So, you can change your loop like this:

```py
for el in root.iter():
    name = el.prefix + ':' + etree.QName(el).localname if el.prefix else etree.QName(el).localname
    print("Element", name)
    for a in el.attrib:
        print("  Attribute", uri2prefix(a, el.nsmap))
```